# Render Edit after Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After creating a new object I want to take the user straight to the edit page for that object.

If I do that with

```
if @object.save
      flash[:success] = "Object added!"
      render 'edit
```

I get an "undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass" error.

If I go to the index view and click through to the edit view for that object I can edit it just fine.

Do I need to use redirect_to rather than render? and if so what is the correct way to phrase it?

Comment: With `render 'edit'` your `edit` action does not get called, only the `edit` template renders.  so, yes you should be redirecting to `edit` action.

Comment: A redirect is not necessary (just for your information, with Rails framework a single request to the server provokes the instanciation of over 6000 objects, sorry can't find back the source). You may consider setting the same variable(s) as for the edit action before rendering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
redirect_to edit_"whatever"_path(@object)
```

It should work.

As you are actually rendering the template, but not the action.

Comment: Great. Will tick. I got close but not close enough.